# How do I get SLF4J to output some logging statements?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm using SLF4J for the first time in my Maven project, but I can't get it to output anything (its creators evidently don't subscribe to the "useful default behavior" philosophy).

I added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.sli4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>sli4j-slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UdpRemoteConnection.class);

      ...

logger.error("test error");
```

Right now I don't need anything fancy, I just need it to log to the console.  How do I enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using Sli4j instead of Slf4j.
Try to use Slf4j directly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

(I use 1.5.11 as slg4j.version, but latest available is 1.6.1)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  And this should log to console without any additional configuration?

Comment: Yes, slf4j-simple just outputs to console starting with info level and above. Personally I don't think it's a very good idea to use it. It's better to use slf4j-jdk14 to log into the default Jdk logger.

Answer (score 2):

My usual config for Java projects with Maven:

pom.xml:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.26</version>
</dependency>
...
```

src/main/resources/logback.xml or/and src/test/resources/logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) is a implementation of [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and the successor of [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).